# Change color of listitem during default PointerDownThemeAnimation

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

what I try:
You click/tapp a listitem --> its background changes the color (like a button on click).

When you click/tapp a listitem the PointerDownThemeAnimation was played (I think so).

My Question:
Is it possible to influence the color the default PointerDownThemeAnimation uses?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the background color of a list view item *only while it is being tapped* (i.e. once you release your finger off the list view item, it will revert back to previous color), then you can just modify the default `ListViewItem` template with this style (the modified section is indicated):

```xml
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
    <Setter Property="IsHoldingEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMargin}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Border x:Name="OuterContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentScaleTransform"/>
                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualTransition>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TiltContainer"/>

                                    <!-- BEGIN MODIFICATION -->
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorder"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                            KeyTime="0"
                                            Value="Red" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <!-- END MODIFICATION -->

                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="CheckboxPressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxTiltContainer"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemDisabledThemeOpacity}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedEarmark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedGlyph">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckGlyph"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedCheckMark"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataVirtualizationStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataAvailable"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="DataPlaceholder">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextBlock">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderRect">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MultiSelectStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="ListMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="NoMultiSelect"/>
                                <VisualTransition From="NoMultiSelect" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.15" To="ListMultiSelect"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoMultiSelect"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ListMultiSelect">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentTranslateX}" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="GridMultiSelect">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="SelectedBorder"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderModeStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition From="ReorderEnabled" GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.2" To="ReorderDisabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReorderEnabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DropTargetItemThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OuterContainer"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Reorderable">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentScaleTransform">
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.075" Value="1.05"/>
                                        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2" Value="1.0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReorderDisabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ReorderHintStates">
                            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2" To="NoReorderHint"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualState x:Name="NoReorderHint"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Bottom" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Right" ToOffset="{ThemeResource ListViewItemReorderHintThemeOffset}" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Top" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftReorderHint">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DragOverThemeAnimation Direction="Left" ToOffset="0" Storyboard.TargetName="ReorderHintContent"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ReorderHintContent" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border x:Name="CheckboxTiltContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{ThemeResource ListViewItemMultiselectCheckBoxMargin}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Border x:Name="CheckboxOuterContainer">
                                <Border.Clip>
                                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,25.5,25.5"/>
                                </Border.Clip>
                                <Grid x:Name="CheckboxContainer">
                                    <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="CheckboxContainerTranslateTransform" X="{ThemeResource ListViewItemContentOffsetX}"/>
                                    </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="NormalRectangle" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="25.5" Stroke="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource CheckBoxBorderThemeThickness}" Width="25.5"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="CheckGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource CheckBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="2.5" StrokeLineJoin="Round" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="18.5"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="ContentContainer">
                            <Border x:Name="TiltContainer">
                                <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentBorderTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="PlaceholderTextBlock" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" Foreground="{x:Null}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0" Text="Xg"/>
                                        <Rectangle x:Name="PlaceholderRect" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="SelectedBorder" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="{ThemeResource GridViewItemMultiselectBorderThickness}" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0">
                            <Grid x:Name="SelectedCheckMark" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="34" Opacity="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="34">
                                <Path x:Name="SelectedEarmark" Data="M0,0 L40,0 L40,40 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSelectedBackgroundThemeBrush}" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                <Path x:Name="SelectedGlyph" Data="M0,123 L39,93 L124,164 L256,18 L295,49 L124,240 z" Fill="{ThemeResource ListViewItemCheckThemeBrush}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="14.5" Margin="0,1,1,0" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Put this style in your page or app resource dictionary, then you can apply it to your list view like this:

```xml
<ListView ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle1}" />
```

---

FYI: To obtain this style definition, right click your list view in the XAML designer -> Edit Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Item Container -> Edit a Copy.

Comment: Rely helpfull! Thanks a lot. Especially the hint to get the Template, because the templates on the microsoft-sites are not the ones used in phone...